# Is there a way to write index in array like A(I) instead of A(A'First + I)?

Tags: arrays, ada

I have to write `A(A'First + I)` to be independent from index definition. It can be somewhat hard to read when there are a lot of them. A small example for the benefit of simplicity:

```vhdl
procedure Dot_Accumulate (A : Number_Array; B : Number_Array; N : Natural; R : in out Number) is
begin
   for I in 0 .. N - 1 loop
      R := R + A(A'First + I) * B(B'First + I);
   end loop;
end;
```

I want the code to look like this instead:

```vhdl
procedure Dot_Accumulate (A : Number_Array; B : Number_Array; N : Natural; R : in out Number) is
begin
   for I in 0 .. N - 1 loop
      R := R + A(I) * B(I);
   end loop;
end;
```

Code lines can grow a lot wider than example I gave because of repeated `A'First + I`

Answer (score 3):

if `Number_Array` is a constrained array type, just do:

```
for I in Number_Array'Range loop
   R := R + A(I) * B(I);
end loop;
```

EDIT:

If you don't mind the extra copying, you can do this for unconstrained arrays (Notice how `N` is eliminated by taking the length of the shortest array):

```
procedure Dot_Accumulate (A : Number_Array; B : Number_Array; R : in out Number) is

  subtype N_A is Number_Array(1..My_Index_Type'Min(A'Length, B'Length));

  Ax : N_A := N_A(A(A'First..A'First+N_A'Length-1));
  Bx : N_A := N_A(B(B'First..B'First+N_A'Length-1));
begin
   for I in N_A'Range loop
      R := R + Ax(I) * Bx(I);
   end loop;
end Dot_Accumulate;
```

Comment: The way to go language-wise. No need to pass an extra parmater N: The info is already in the array. Also potentially faster because the compiler can omit index range checks; after all, the index is guaranteed to be within the array's bounds.

Comment: Constrained array type also constrains the dot product which should work for any dimension. Would there be any solution for unconstrained array type?

Comment: @PeterSchneider the N parameter is there in case of array A or B would have different length. Dot product is commutative so there should be no consequence if I would swap A and B.

Comment: Hmmm...  am I missing something? There is only one N, so how could it be used to communicate different lenghts? And is it not necessary for the lenghts to be equal for dot multiplication?

Comment: With respect to constrained/unconstrained: I haven't touched Ada for a long time but I think while an array *type* can be unconstrained, an array *object* is always constrained, and you can apply the Range attribute to the object, i.e. write `for I in A'Range loop`.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Yes, but if `Number_Array` is unconstrained, `B'Range` may differ from `A'Range`

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is to fix `Number_Array'First`:

```
type Number_Array is array (Positive range <>) of Number
  with Dynamic_Predicate => Number_Array'First = 1;
```

Then you can write your loop:

```
for I in 1 .. N loop
   R := R + A (I) * B (I);
end loop;
```

But besides that, your example is unbelievably ugly.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Yes that ugly part is my point. I didn't want to write that I thought others might think otherwise but for me it looks much cleaner without A'First.

Comment: @Jossi it is the procedure declaration which is ugly (to my eyes).

Answer (score 0):

This is a another option:

```vhdl
procedure Dot_Accumulate (A : Number_Array; B : Number_Array; R : in out Number) with
  Pre => A'Length = B'Length;

procedure Dot_Accumulate (A : Number_Array; B : Number_Array; R : in out Number) is
   subtype Common_Range is Number_Array (1 .. A'Length);
   Ax : Common_Range with Address => A'Address;
   Bx : Common_Range with Address => B'Address;
begin
   for I in Common_Range'Range loop
      R := R + Ax(I) * Bx(I);
   end loop;
end;
```

A and B is ensured to have the same length so there is no need to pass N parameter. And I don't think this will decrease the performance because Ax is using the same memory as A.